# How do I make flex items shrink to their smallest fitting size, but the same size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a row of buttons, where the buttons will be the same size, but as small as possible - so each being the same size as the largest button.

How can I do this?

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.item {
  background-color: #eef;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">this one is quite long</div>
  <div class="item">short</div>
</div>
```

Comment: to my knowledge you're going to have to declare some variety of width for the flex items to be.

Comment: ^Thanks - that works for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flexbox` can do a lot but not all. For this `grid` would be good, but since it lacks good browser support, its older "version" `table` might be an option.

Here is a script free, dynamic solution, using `display: inline-table`.

```css
.container,
.item {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  text-align: right;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-table;
  border-spacing: 10px 5px;
}
.item {
  background-color: #eef;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">this one is quite long</div>
    <div class="item">shorter</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to restore the margin around the buttons with border-spacing

Comment: Good answer. Nowadays it's fancy to say **never** use tables, but sometimes this is what is needed ...

Comment: @vals Thanks ... good to be from the past to know some of what it can do :)

Comment: @LGSon for what it's worth - here's a css grid solution: https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/rwWaYq?editors=1100#0 (I used `inline-grid` here but there may also be a way to do this with a regular grid - not sure)

Comment: @Danield Thanks, that is great ... I think you should post it (I'll upvote it). I know one can do _almost_ anything with CSS Grid, though I can't, yet. Haven't go the time to dive into it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with flexbox, but for what it's worth, this can be achieved with the [**CSS Grid Layout Module**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/).

```css
.container,
.item {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  text-align: right;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eef;
  text-align: left;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">this one is quite long</div>
    <div class="item">shorter</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/rwWaYq?editors=1100#0)

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.container {
  text-align: right; 
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

It's worth noting here that `flex-grow: 1` (for flex items) works a bit different here than [flexible lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit) - `1fr` for css grids.

```css
.container,
.item {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  text-align: right;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eef;
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">this one is quite long</div>
    <div class="item">shorter</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's almost identical code - except that flex-grow seems to wrap the first item's long text on to a new line.